# How to delete an element from a sparse array?

Tags: javascript

I want to know the right way to delete an element in sparse array but keep the indices of others the same.

I don't want to use splice as it'd change the indexes of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and remove the item. The place is now sparse.

```js
var array = [, , 1, 2, 3];

console.log(array);

delete array[3];

console.log(array);

array.forEach(v => console.log(v)); // shows two elements
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```